# C# Excel chart alternative text

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for connection with Excel 2013 to generate chart. I try to get access to alternative text on chart. If chart is on the sheets I am using this script:

```
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
        oXL =(Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
        oSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;
        oSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Title = "2016-02-17 A$16$";
```

Until charts is on sheet it work, issue is when chart is standalone chart, in this case  I am using this code:

```
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Chart cht;
        oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

        oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;
        cht = (Excel.Chart)oWB.ActiveChart;
        chart.Shapes.Item(1).Title = "2016-02-17 A$16$";
```

In this cases When I try Count Shapes is give me 0 and I don't know how to get access to alternative text.

I am checked in VBA this as well, however in C# event if I use this code:

```
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel.Workbook oWB;
        Excel.Worksheet oWS;


        oXL = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
        oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook;

        oWS = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[1];

        oWS.Shapes.Item(1).Title = "2016-02-17 A$16$";
        oWS.Shapes.Item(1).AlternativeText= "2016-02-17 A$16$";
```

If chart is standalone chart sheet, count of the shape is still 0.

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: Because I am using C# in Visual Studio 2013 for connection with Excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, you can assign Alt text to a shape that is embedded in a worksheet or chart sheet. A chart embedded in a worksheet is actually enclosed in a shape (a special shape called a ChartObject). When you use

ActiveWorkbook.Shapes.Items(1)

you are referencing a shape embedded in the worksheet, which in your case is also a ChartObject that contains your chart. You are assigning the Alt text to this ChartObject, the container for the chart, not to the chart itself.

Okay, so this is working for you.

A chart on its own sheet is not embedded in a shape. It is both a chart and a sheet (not a worksheet, which is also a sheet, but a chart sheet). There is no shape to assign the Alt text to.

You can assign Alt text to a chart sheet in the Excel UI, and if you change the position of the chart from a chart sheet to an object embedded in another sheet, Excel remembers the Atl text.

But the OM for the Alt text for the chart sheet looks broken. If I record an Excel VBA macro while assigning Alt text to an embedded chart (with ChartObject name "Chart 1"), this is the code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Title = "Embedded Chart Alt Text"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").AlternativeText = "Embedded Chart Description"
```

If I record an Excel VBA macro while assigning Alt text to a chart sheet (sheet name "Chart1"), I get almost identical code:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").Title = "Chart Sheet Alt Text"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 1").AlternativeText = "Chart Sheet Description"
```

The Alt text and description are saved, because I used the Excel UI to assign them, but the code makes no sense. The activesheet is the chart, and it contains no shapes, especially not one named "Chart 1". I don't know where "Chart 1" comes from, because the chart was "Chart 2" before I moved it to its own chart sheet.

This is a bug. I can see no hook in the Excel object model to Alt text for a chart sheet (in fact, it really only makes sense for an embedded shape, since it's used in images embedded in web pages). The code recorded while assigning Alt text to a chart sheet makes no sense, and playing it back results in errors because "Chart 1" cannot be found.

I'll report the bug, but you should probably go back to using embedded charts.

Comment: I am afraid I can’t use embedded charts. I have too many of them. Any other idea, how to read this properties?

Comment: No. The VBA object model does not allow for these properties on chart sheets.

Comment: What do you mean, by too many charts? It would seem that you could keep them more organized by embedding certain ones together according to some kind of scheme.